Convert default coordinate system React-Leaflet
I'm trying to make a request from the NASA satellite, but when I use 3857 it doesn't show the region I want, and in 4326 it does. That's the problem, when I use 4326 it moves on the map and I can't see it, I thought about changing the react-leaflet coordinate to 4326 but I can't. Any suggestion?

"GOES-East":
"https://gitc.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts/epsg4326/best/wmts.cgi?layer=GOES-East_ABI_GeoColor&tilematrixset=1km&Service=WMTS&Request=GetTile&Version=1.0.0&Format=image/png&TileMatrix={z}&TileCol={x}&TileRow={y}",

const Map = () => {
   ...

   return (
      <MapContainer
                center={[mapState.lat, mapState.lng]}
                zoom={mapState.zoom}
                style={{
                    flexGrow: 1,
                }}
            >  
                <TileLayer
                    key={activeSatellite}
                    url={satelliteUrls[activeSatellite]}
                    attribution="NASA"
                />
        
            </MapContainer>
        </div>
    );
};



Can you share your actual request (instead of placeholders used in your query) to make this reproducible for others? And, if possible, same would apply to your code.

Leaflet supports only one CRS per map, you cannot mix layers which have different CRS. Do you want to display only NASA satellite layer? Because in the image there are two layers with obviously different CRS.
